# Corrupt xml is getting downloaded when downloading .xml file from artifactory using python

Tags: python, request, artifactory

I am using below script to download all the xml files present in an artifactory directory (subfoldername contains various .xml files)

```
from artifactory import ArtifactoryPath
import shutil,os,requests

url="https://artifactory.xxx.com/artifactory/foldername/subfoldername/"
logdirectory='C:\\subfoldername'
if not os.path.exists(logdirectory):
            os.mkdir(logdirectory)
os.chdir(logdirectory)
xmlfiles = ArtifactoryPath(url,auth=(username, password))
for element in xmlfiles:
    print (element )
    xmlname=str(element).split("/")[-1]
    print(xmlname)
    with requests.get(element , auth=(username, password), stream=True) as r:
         with open(xmlname, 'wb') as f:
         shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
```

It is downloading the xml files with correct name but when i try to open the files it shows corrupted data.
[image]

PS: I have also tried below method present on (https://pypi.org/project/artifactory/) but it also results in same corrupted xml using my code for path and authentication. Pasted below code for quick reference

```
from artifactory import ArtifactoryPath
path = ArtifactoryPath(
    "http://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/distributions/org/apache/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.11.tar.gz")

with path.open() as fd:
    with open("tomcat.tar.gz", "wb") as out:
        out.write(fd.read())
```

please suggest how can i download xml files without getting them corrupt

Comment: What is the `with path.open() as fd:` in the last snippet of code you shared? That doesn't appear in the original program, right?

Comment: its example on https://pypi.org/project/artifactory/ to download code

Comment: In the loop `for xml in xmlfiles:`, what's in `xml`?

Comment: its variable name

Comment: Whose variable name? Btw, can we use that link for testing?

Comment: Its varible for "for" loop, sorry cannot use link as its internal company url which require authentication

Comment: _Its varible for "for" loop_ Yes, I get that, I was asking what it contains, what it refers to.

Comment: its contains the link of xml file with complete path of artifactory example: https://artifactory.xxx.com/artifactory/foldername/subfoldername/abc.xml

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206401/discussion-between-amc-and-thebadguy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this works:

```py
for element in xmlfiles:
    print(element)
    xmlname= str(element).split("/")[-1]
    print(xmlname)
    req = requests.get(element , auth=(username, password))
         with open(xmlname, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(req.content)
```

WIP